# Debug python - Error: No main class specified?

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I installed Intellij 2019 with python plugin. And I opened a directory with python scripts. I'm going to debug `script1.py` in the directory.

In the "Project Structure" window, I added new Python in the field "Project SDK".

Then, I went to "Run/Debug configurations" folder and clicked the `+` and added a new `Application`, I need an command line argument so I filled the field "Program arguments:" with my arguments.

However, at the bottom it shows a read error message: "Error: No main class specified". And I cannot run the python script. What I missed to set up the intellij to run python script?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Python run configuration instead. Although creating run configurations manually is inconvenient and I would recommend using a context menu or a shortcut so that IDE does it automatically:
[image]

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-applications.html for more details.